# Rv water heater turns on when only using cold water at the faucet

Tags: water, water-heater

Why does the water heater in my camper turn on  when I am only using the cold water at the faucet?

Comment: Is it a single-handle faucet or separate hot/cold handles?

Comment: Is it a tank-type heater or an on-demand/instant heater? How do you know that it turns on? (a light somewhere illuminates, hot water comes out the cold faucet, etc?)